2d tilemap or 3d isometric?
I am learning unity for fun and to experience myself I would like to recreate my childhood game : master of olympus zeus. Should I go 2D with tilemap or 3D with camera setup to reproduce the isometric ?

You should do 2D with a tilemap, as that's how it looks like the game was made. When you make/get 2D assets, make them look 3d if you want the same isometric style of the game. Also, it's much easier to work in simple 2d if you are a beginner to Unity.
